# How to replace %7C and %20 from url using jquery?

Tags: jquery

code:

```
str = noida | hotel paradise;
a = str.replace(/ /g, "+");
b = a.replace(/\ | /g,"+");
alert(b);
```

In this code I have a string `noida | hotel paradise` and I want to replace `|` and space with `+` operator which is not working yet. When I click on button it show me result like `noida+|+Ramada+Phuket+Deevana+Patong` but I want `noida+Ramada+Phuket+Deevana+Patong`. So, How can I fix this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Your code block and your expected results use completely different strings, and the title of the question doesn't appear to relate to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a simple character class with space and `|` in it, and you probably want a "one or more" quantifier (`+`):

```
a = str.replace(/[ |]+/g, "+");
alert(a);
```

Live Example:

```js
var str = "noida | hotel paradise";
var a = str.replace(/[ |]+/g, "+");
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second regex has an issue: it escapes the space with a backslash which is not necessary, but it does not escape the pipe symbol, which *is* necessary. Also, it requires a space around the pipe which is not what you are requiring in your question. So change it to:

```
b = a.replace(/\|/g,"+");
```

You can do both replacements in one go, and make repetitions to be only replaced with one plus:

```
b = str.replace(/[ |]+/g, "+")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
var str = 'noida | hotel paradise'
var replaced = str.replace(/\|/g, '+').replace(/ /g, '+').replace(/\+\+/, '');
console.log(replaced);
```

First replace all `|` and  to `+`, and then remove duplicated `+`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'noida | hotel paradise;'
a = str.replace(/[|\s]+/g, "+");
alert(a);
```

---

try this

```js
str = 'noida | hotel paradise;'
a = str.replace(/[|\s]+/g, "+");
alert(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also do something like.

```
"noida | hotel paradise".replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '+');
//"noida+hotel+paradise"
```